# Can I programmatically force changes to a file to propagate to all NFS clients?

Tags: php, file-io, nfs, haproxy

I have a CMS built in PHP which stores the list of pages, page navigation structure, and the content of pages in files on disk. This application is hosted on a cluster of Apache/php-fpm servers which are behind a haproxy server. These servers mount the Apache DocumentRoot directory via NFS from a central file server, so all the changes made from the CMS get written to files on the NFS share.

I have found that, unless I mount the NFS share with the `noac` option, changes made may take up to 5-10 seconds to propagate to all servers in the cluster; meaning when multiple changes are made in rapid succession, the final change sometimes overwrites the earlier changes because the final change may go to a server which has not received the earlier changes yet.

However, when using the `noac` mount option, there's a 2-5 second delay in accessing the content on the visitor side, which is completely unacceptable.

Is there a way to programmatically force changes to a file on an NFS share to propigate to all clients, or to cause all clients to flush their cache of that file?

Comment: You can never force a client to do anything it doesn't want to.

Comment: It had better want to do what I want it to or it will be replaced! ;-)

Comment: That may actually not be such a terrible idea.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm looking at Samba as an alternative; open to suggestions! (I was going to post *that* question on ServerFault)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same issue with NFS parameter `cto` in combination with apache directives `EnableMMAP Off` and `EnableSendFile Off`. the `noac` parameter had the same symptoms you wrote about.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any NFS-level option to achieve what you want BUT if the applications accessing those files are under your control then you can make every file open use the `O_DIRECT` option - this bypasses any local NFS cache for any file opened this way...

A remark:

You write that `noac` leads to a delay of 2-5 seconds.. this seems to point to a network- and/or storage-level problem or to "far to many files/directories within one directory"...

Comment: Thanks for the advice -- I'll research this more. As far as the network/storage level problem, there's a gigabit link between the NFS server and the application servers... so that shouldn't be an issue...